# Prestashop 1.7.7. Error When Proceed to Checkout

Tags: prestashop, checkout

Like I explain at the title this issue it's related with the checkout of prestashop version 1.7.7.0.

When I add I product to the cart, and then I press the button to proceed to the checkout I have this issue:

```
[21-Jun-2021 22:39:57 Europe/Madrid] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Cart::checkAllProductsAreStillAvailableInThisState() in /home/public_html/classes/checkout/CheckoutPaymentStep.php:48
Stack trace:
#0 /home/public_html/classes/checkout/CheckoutProcess.php(59): CheckoutPaymentStepCore->handleRequest(Array)
#1 /home/public_html/controllers/front/OrderController.php(278): CheckoutProcessCore->handleRequest(Array)
#2 /home/public_html/classes/controller/Controller.php(306): OrderControllerCore->initContent()
#3 /home/public_html/classes/Dispatcher.php(518): ControllerCore->run()
#4 /home/public_html/index.php(28): DispatcherCore->dispatch()
#5 {main}
  thrown in /home/public_html/classes/checkout/CheckoutPaymentStep.php on line 48
```

I have made some test:

- Disable all the modules and have only to the native ones of Prestashop.
- Tried with a clean install and always i have the same problem.
- No matters if it's the default theme or the bought one.
- Delete the cache of prestashop...

Clearly i'm desesperate with this problem... Any help will be so apreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Hello again for all the community,

I have solve the problem by commenting some lines of code.

Get this archive and edit it.
Classes > Checkout > CheckoutPaymentStep.php

```
public function handleRequest(array $requestParams = [])
    {
        $cart = $this->getCheckoutSession()->getCart();
        $allProductsInStock = $cart->isAllProductsInStock();
        //$allProductsExist = $cart->checkAllProductsAreStillAvailableInThisState(); /*-- Comment this --*/
        //$allProductsHaveMinimalQuantity = $cart->checkAllProductsHaveMinimalQuantities(); /*-- Comment this --*/

        //if ($allProductsInStock !== true || $allProductsExist !== true || $allProductsHaveMinimalQuantity !== true) /*-- Change this one --*/
        if ($allProductsInStock !== true) {
            $cartShowUrl = $this->context->link->getPageLink(
                'cart',
                null,
                $this->context->language->id,
                [
                    'action' => 'show',
                ],
                false,
                null,
                false
            );
            Tools::redirect($cartShowUrl);
        }

        if (isset($requestParams['select_payment_option'])) {
            $this->selected_payment_option = $requestParams['select_payment_option'];
        }

        $this->setTitle(
            $this->getTranslator()->trans(
                'Payment',
                [],
                'Shop.Theme.Checkout'
            )
        );
    }
```

For now all goes well and we can process to the checkout. Hope if someone have the same problem, could help you.

Nancy.

Comment: Well - skipping code execution is not a good solution IMHO :) As far as I can see the "checkAllProductsAreStillAvailableInThisState" method is present in original in Prestashop 1.7.7.0 Cart.php file, so you either have a wrong version core Cart.php file or (most likely) you have an overriden Cart.php in /override/classes folder. 

Try replacing classes/Cart.php from original Prestashop 1.7.7.0 archive and see what's happen first.

Comment: Hi @user3256843,

I totally agree with you, but since I had already tried everything ... The reality was that when I comment that lines and see that I continued, you breathe a sigh of relief (even if it is a totally bad patch).

I will try anyway to verify that, as you indicate, a file has not been modified, including cart.php.

Thanks for your answer, I will give feedback as soon as possible.